# How to make this type of Activity Layout in My Android App?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFwLM.png)

In This Image You Can See The Layout Of Screen.
Can You Please Say Me How To Make This Type Of Layout?
Help is Appreciated...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about take a look to official doc?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Maybe if you are specificest...